# Fetch contents of ContentDocument JSON in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am developing a managed package for an ISV.
One of the components designs would be to fetch a JSON file attached to a record and parse it directly in LWC.
This is done to avoid 131072 field limits in the records.

I tried using `fetch()` API but, unsurprisingly, it seems to run into the CSP issues for me.

How can I distribute this in a managed package if the trusted site would be the site which holds documents for the subscriber's org.

E.g. I am trying to do:

```
fetch('/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/<docId>?operationContext=S1', {
    method: "GET",
    mode: 'no-cors'
  })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response); 
    });
```

I tried specifying full instance URL or my document force URL and in all cases without adding URL to Trusted CSP I can't get the attachment content.

Comment: Do you expect the file to potentially be more than 6MB? If not, you could just query it in Apex and return the value.

Comment: Yeah I did consider that as an option @sfdcfox but a) this is created in the subscriber org so there is no guarantee that it stays under although you'd hope so and b) I was really hoping to avoid custom Apex for this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `getRecord` wire call to get the data you want without writing Apex.

You need to wire `getRecord` twice - First, to get the latest `Content Version Id` from the **ContentDocument**, and second, to get the data from **ContentVersion**. You will need to then decode the Base64 response using the JS function `atob`

```js
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import VERSION_DATA_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/ContentVersion.VersionData';
import CONTENT_VERSION_ID from '@salesforce/schema/ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId';

export default class Demo extends LightningElement {
  
  @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '<docid>', fields: [CONTENT_VERSION_ID] })
  contentdocument;

  @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$contentVersionId', fields: [VERSION_DATA_FIELD] })
  contentversion;

  get contentVersionId(){
    return getFieldValue(this.contentdocument.data, CONTENT_VERSION_ID);
  }

  get versiondata(){
    let fieldValue = getFieldValue(this.contentversion.data, VERSION_DATA_FIELD);
    if(fieldValue){
      return atob(fieldValue);
      // to return a JSON object instead of a string, use the line below
      // return JSON.parse( atob(fieldValue) );
    }
     return '';
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi @Aditya Naag , does using the approach mentioned by you will impact the Salesforce AppExchange Security Review any way because we thought of using the above mentioned approach for our managed package.